# Does Empty indexes exists in memory

Tags: php, arrays, memory

i have created an array like

```
arr[15] = "hello";
arr[21] = "world";
```

there are empty indexes from `0` to `14` and `15` to `20` . does these empty indexes are stored in memory or not . do they cause memory consumption . is it ok to have random indexes for array thanks

Comment: From where the empty indexes are created?

Comment: Unless you specify `$arr[14]=0;` they don't exist, so don't consume memory. The "index" is merely an pointer to a location - it doesn't mean that every location preceding it has to exist :)

Comment: very easy to chek with if(isset(arr[10]))  .. blabla

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25114841/2637490) - despite different context, it explains array structure (prior to PHP 7) quite well

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays are associative, also known as dictionaries, also known as hashmaps, also known as key-value store. There's no relationship between keys, meaning the existence of a key `15` does not imply the existence of a key `14`, just as the existence of a key `'foo'` does not imply the existence of a key `'bar'`. PHP arrays are therefore all *sparse*. When you create the key `15` PHP does *not* populate keys `0`-`14`. They do not exist and do not occupy memory.

Answer (score 0):

> here are empty indexes from 0 to 14 and 15 to 20 . does these empty indexes are stored in memory or not . do they cause memory consumption

**If you have created an array which consists these keys,then Yes they will occupy memory**

If you're creating an `array` as

```
$array = array();
var_dump(isset($array));//bool(true)
```

Then its also consume memory too. So if your array consist the empty value then it'll be consuming memory too

> Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".

[**Check Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Reason for downvoting

Comment: You're saying that non-existing keys occupy memory, which is plain wrong.

Comment: Nope @deceze I'm not saying that but when I read my answer I got the point why I'm being downvoted

Comment: I think the OP's phrasing is a bit misleading. By "empty" I assume they mean *non-existent*, i.e. those keys were **never created**. Starting your answer with **"Yes"** is still pretty easy to misunderstand.

Comment: Yep you're right OP's phrasing is a bit misleading. That's why I've specified _Yes they will occupy memory if you have created an array which consists these keys_