# How to stream creation of a JSON File?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

Am trying to create a JSON file from a large dump of a database query, and works when I set a LIMIT to 100000 rows being returned, but when I want all rows to be returned, it just goes to a 502 Error (The page request was canceled because it took too long to complete).  Wondering if there is a way that I can streamline the creation of a JSON File in bits using php, or if there is a Library out there that will allow me to build the json file in parts?

Basically am running a .php file here to attempt to get all orders in json format from woocommerce, since the plugin I purchased "CSV Import Suite" does not work when importing orders, it just stays in the queue.

So, I decided to try and export all orders myself, but keep hitting a 502 Error Page and it never creates the .json file either, so am thinking I need a way to stream this somehow.  Any help on this would be appreciated...

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush(TRUE);
ob_end_flush();

global $wpdb, $root_dir;

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    $root_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';
else
    $root_dir = ABSPATH;


$download = isset($_GET['download']);

// Allows us to use WP functions in a .php file without 404 headers!
require_once($root_dir . 'wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();

if (empty($download))
    $wp->send_headers();

// exclude
$exclude_post_statuses = array('trash', 'wc-refunded', 'wc_cancelled');


$start_date = !empty($_GET['start_date']) ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['start_date']) : '';
$end_date = !empty($_GET['end_date']) ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['end_date']) : '';


$order_db = array(
    'columns' => array(
        'p' => array('ID', 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content', 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_status', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'post_password', 'post_name', 'to_ping', 'pinged', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_content_filtered', 'post_parent', 'guid', 'menu_order', 'post_type', 'post_mime_type', 'comment_count'),
        'pm' => array('meta_id', 'post_id', 'meta_key', 'meta_value'),
        'oi' => array('order_item_id', 'order_item_name', 'order_item_type', 'order_id'),
        'oim' => array('meta_id', 'order_item_id', 'meta_key', 'meta_value')
    )
);

$select_data = '';
$total_columns = count($order_db['columns']);
$i = 1;

foreach($order_db['columns'] as $column_key => $columns)
{
    $select_data .= implode(', ', array_map(
        function ($v, $k) { return $k . '.' . $v . ' AS ' . $k . '_' . $v; },
        $columns,
        array_fill(0, count($columns), $column_key)
    ));

    if ($i < $total_columns)
        $select_data .= ', ';

    $i++;
}

// HUGE DATABASE DUMP HERE, needs to be converted to JSON, after getting all columns of all tables...
$orders_query = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT ' . $select_data . '
    FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p
    INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' AS pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
    LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON (oi.order_id = p.ID)
    LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON (oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id)
    WHERE p.post_type = "shop_order"' . (!empty($exclude_post_statuses) ? ' AND p.post_status NOT IN ("' . implode('","', $exclude_post_statuses) . '")' : '') . (!empty($start_date) ? ' AND post_date >= "' . $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . (!empty($end_date) ? ' AND post_date <= "' . $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . '
    ORDER BY p.ID ASC', ARRAY_A);

$json = array();

if (!empty($orders_query))
{
    foreach($orders_query as $order_query)
    {
        if (!isset($json[$order_query['p_post_type']], $json[$order_query['p_post_type']][$order_query['p_post_name']]))
            $json[$order_query['p_post_type']][$order_query['p_post_name']] = array(
                'posts' => array(),
                'postmeta' => array(),
                'woocommerce_order_items' => array(),
                'woocommerce_order_itemmeta' => array()
            );

        if (!empty($order_query['p_ID']))
            $json[$order_query['p_post_type']][$order_query['p_post_name']]['posts'][$order_query['p_ID']] = array_filter($order_query, function($k) {
                $is_p = strpos($k, 'p_');
                return $is_p !== FALSE && empty($is_p);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

        if (!empty($order_query['pm_meta_id']))
            $json[$order_query['p_post_type']][$order_query['p_post_name']]['postmeta'][$order_query['pm_meta_id']] = array_filter($order_query, function($k) {
                $is_pm = strpos($k, 'pm_');
                return $is_pm !== FALSE && empty($is_pm);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

        if (!empty($order_query['oi_order_item_id']))
            $json[$order_query['p_post_type']][$order_query['p_post_name']]['woocommerce_order_items'][$order_query['oi_order_item_id']] = array_filter($order_query, function($k) {
                $is_io = strpos($k, 'oi_');
                return $is_io !== FALSE && empty($is_io);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);


        if (!empty($order_query['oim_meta_id']))
            $json[$order_query['p_post_type']][$order_query['p_post_name']]['woocommerce_order_itemmeta'][$order_query['oim_meta_id']] = array_filter($order_query, function($k) {
                $is_oim = strpos($k, 'oim_');
                return $is_oim !== FALSE && empty($is_oim);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    }
}

// Downloading or viewing?
if (!empty($download))
{
    // Outputs json in a textarea for you to copy and paste into a .json file for import...

    if (!empty($json))
    {
        $filename = uniqid('orders_') . '.json';

        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
        fclose($fp);


        $size   = filesize($root_dir . '/' . $filename);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\""); 
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

        readfile($root_dir . '/' . $filename);
    }

}
else
{
    // Outputs json in a textarea for you to copy and paste into a .json file for import...
    if (!empty($json))
        echo '<textarea cols="200" rows="50">', json_encode($json), '</textarea>';
}
```

The JSON File created could be a well over 500 MB, and possibly even up to 1 Gig of data.  So, I believe PHP is running out of memory here, and needs to be processed bit by bit somehow, either in the background, or completely, without hitting the php memory limit.  I believe the memory limit is set to 1024 MB, which is pretty high, but not high enough and tbh, for what I'm doing, I don't think we can ever have enough memory to perform the operation as is.  Something needs to change in how I process the json and/or download it.  And I do not want to create multiple json files, please only 1 JSON file.

Comment: I am really curious about the software that will consume the generated json file! will that software really need a 1Gb data to process ! i ask this because reading a large json file is pain in the a$$, so writing it might be a bigger pain than that.

Comment: I am not sure about your purpose of retrieving all data at once. Why don't you limit the retrieving data by 1000 rows and create separate JSON files ?

Comment: Why do you think that "streaming" will solve your problem? What exactly do you mean by this term? Why not dump smaller files that contain excerpts? This would also speedup reading the files into the other system

Comment: I would use line delimited json (ldjson) instead of full json. This way each line can be separately processed and this way it is super suitable for streaming. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Delimited_JSON

Comment: No one has provided any means of how to stream creation of a json file however.  So sad, I will have to award points to a person who provided a way to debug the issue only....

Comment: Did you consider max_allowd_packet in mysql?

Comment: @SolomonClosson, please look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 7):

I think there might be couple of issues. Firstly I would suggest you do some profiling.

```
    // HUGE DATABASE DUMP HERE, needs to be converted to JSON, after getting all columns of all tables...
    echo 'Start Time: '. date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    echo ' Memory Usage: ' . (memory_get_usage()/1048576) . ' MB \n';

    $orders_query = $wpdb->get_results('
        SELECT ' . $select_data . '
        FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p
        INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' AS pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
        LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON (oi.order_id = p.ID)
        LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON (oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id)
        WHERE p.post_type = "shop_order"' . (!empty($exclude_post_statuses) ? ' AND p.post_status NOT IN ("' . implode('","', $exclude_post_statuses) . '")' : '') . (!empty($start_date) ? ' AND post_date >= "' . $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . (!empty($end_date) ? ' AND post_date <= "' . $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . '
        ORDER BY p.ID ASC', ARRAY_A);

    echo 'End Time: '. date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    echo ' Memory Usage: ' . (memory_get_usage()/1048576) . ' MB \n';
    die('Finished');

    $json = array();
```

The above will help you to know how much memory is in use, upto this point. If it fails before it prints 'Finished', we know it is not a json issue. If the script works fine then we can first create a csv file rather json. Since you are running a select query, (at this point) it does not have to be nested json file which you require. A flat structure can be achieved by just creating a CSV file.

```
$csvFile = uniqid('orders') . '.csv';
$fp = fopen($csvFile, 'w');
if (!empty($orders_query))
{
    $firstRow = true;
    foreach($orders_query as $order_query)
    {
        if(true === $firstRow) {
            $keys = array_keys($order_query);
            fputcsv($fp, $order_query);
            $firstRow = false;
        }

        fputcsv($fp, $order_query);
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

If the above works fine you at-least have a csv file to work with.

At this point I am not sure how complex is your data structure nested. For e.g how many distinct values exist for 'p_post_type' and 'p_post_name' you are having. You might require to parse the csv file and create multiple json file for each *['p_post_type']['p_post_name']['posts'], ['p_post_type']['p_post_name']['posts'], ['p_post_type']['p_post_name']['woocommerce_order_items'] and ['p_post_type']['p_post_name']['woocommerce_order_itemmeta']*.

If the number of files are few you can write a script to merge them automatically or do them manually. If you have too many nested items, the number of json files that might be created might be a lot and might be hard to merge them and might not be a feasible option.

If the number of json files are lot, I would like to know what is the purpose of having such a huge single json file. If export is an issue import might be an issue too, especially ingesting such a huge json file in memory. I believe if the purpose of creating the json file is to import it in some form, at some stage in future, I think you might have to look at the option of just having a csv file instead, which you use to filter out whatever is required at that point of time.

I hope this helps.

> FURTHER UPDATE

It looks to me that ***$wpdb->get_results*** is using mysqli_query/mysql_query (depending on your configuration) to fetch the results. See [wordpress query docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_do_query/). It is not memory efficient way to fetch the data this way. I believe you might be failing at this point (***$wpdb->get_results***) itself. I would suggest you to run the query without using ***$wpdb***. There is a concept of unbuffered query whenever large data retrieval is required, which has very low impact on the memory. Further information can be found here [mysql unbuffering](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php).

Even if you get past this point, you will still run into memory issues, due to the way how you are storing everything in ***$json*** variable which is eating up lot of your memory. ***$json*** is an array and it would interesting to know how PHP array works. PHP arrays are dynamic and they do not allocate extra memory every time a new element is added, since that would be extremely slow. It instead, increases the array size to the power of two, which means whenever the limit is exhausted it increases the array limit to twice its current limit and in the process tries to increase the memory to twice the limit. This has been less of an issue with PHP 7, since they have made some major changes to the php core. So if you have 2GB data that might be required to be stored in ***$json***, the script might easily allocate anywhere between 3-4 GB memory, depending upon when it hits the limit. Further details can be found here [php array](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html) and [How does PHP memory actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081344/how-does-php-memory-actually-work)

If you consider the overhead of the ***$orders_query*** which is an array combined with overhead of ***$json*** it is quite substantial due to the way PHP array works.

You can also try to create another database B. So while you are reading from database A, you simultaneously start writing data  to database B. In the end you have database B with all the data in it with the power of MySQL. You could also push the same data into a MongoDB which would be lightning fast and might help you with the json nesting you are after. MongoDB is meant to work really efficiently with large datasets.

> JSON STREAMING SOLUTION

Firstly, I would like to say that streaming is sequential/linear process. As such, it is does not have memory of what was added before this point of time or what will added after this point of time. It works in small chunks and that is the reason it is so memory efficient. So when you actually write or read, the responsibility lies with the script, that it maintains a specific order, which is kind of saying you are writing/reading your own json, as streaming only understands text and has no clue about what json is and won't bother itself in writing/reading a correct one.

I have found a library on github https://github.com/skolodyazhnyy/json-stream which would help in you achieving what you want. I have experimented with the code and I can see it will work for you with some tweaks in your code.

I am going to write some pseudo-code for you.

```
//order is important in this query as streaming would require to maintain a proper order.
$query1 = select distinct p_post_type from ...YOUR QUERY... order by p_post_type;
$result1 = based on $query1; 

$filename = 'data.json';
$fh = fopen($filename, "w");
$writer = new Writer($fh);
$writer->enter(Writer::TYPE_OBJECT);  

foreach($result1 as $fields1) {
    $posttype = $fields1['p_post_type'];
    $writer->enter($posttype, Writer::TYPE_ARRAY); 

    $query2 = select distinct p_post_name from ...YOUR QUERY... YOUR WHERE ... and p_post_type= $posttype order by p_post_type,p_post_name;
    $result2 = based on $query2;

    foreach($result2 as $fields2) {
        $postname = $fields1['p_post_name'];
        $writer->enter($postname, Writer::TYPE_ARRAY); 

        $query3 = select ..YOUR COLUMNS.. from ...YOUR QUERY... YOUR WHERE ... and p_post_type= $posttype and p_post_name=$postname where p_ID is not null order by p_ID;
        $result3 = based on $query3;
        foreach($result2 as $field3) {
            $writer->enter('posts', Writer::TYPE_ARRAY); 
            // write an array item
            $writer->write(null, $field3);
        }
        $writer->leave(); 

        $query4 = select ..YOUR COLUMNS.. from ...YOUR QUERY... YOUR WHERE ... and p_post_type= $posttype and p_post_name=$postname where pm_meta_id is not null order by pm_meta_id;
        $result4 = based on $query4;
        foreach($result4 as $field4) {
            $writer->enter('postmeta', Writer::TYPE_ARRAY); 
            // write an array item
            $writer->write(null, $field4);
        }
       $writer->leave(); 

        $query5 = select ..YOUR COLUMNS.. from ...YOUR QUERY... YOUR WHERE ... and p_post_type= $posttype and p_post_name=$postname where oi_order_item_id is not null order by oi_order_item_id;
        $result5 = based on $query5;
        foreach($result5 as $field5) {
            $writer->enter('woocommerce_order_items', Writer::TYPE_ARRAY); 
            // write an array item
            $writer->write(null, $field5);
        }
        $writer->leave(); 

        $query6 = select ..YOUR COLUMNS.. from ...YOUR QUERY... YOUR WHERE ... and p_post_type= $posttype and p_post_name=$postname where oim_meta_id is not null order by oim_meta_id;
        $result6 = based on $query6;
        foreach($result6 as $field6) {
            $writer->enter('woocommerce_order_itemmeta', Writer::TYPE_ARRAY); 
            // write an array item
            $writer->write(null, $field5);
        }
        $writer->leave(); 

    }
$writer->leave(); 
fclose($fh);
```

You might have to start limiting your queries to 10 something until you get it right. Since the code above might not just work as it is. You should be able to read the code in similar fashion as the same library has got a Reader class to help. I have tested both reader and writer and they seem to work fine.

Comment: The server I am exporting from can not allocate enough memory for this operation.  The server I am importing to can however.  In any case, I simply went the tedious route of creating json files for all orders per day, and in some cases, I had to split days up into hours in order for the query to work.  Is definitely a `$wpdb->get_results` issue, seems that it consumes too much memory.  A Raw MySQL query would probably be faster, however, would still not be able to export in a single go, but funny that phpMyAdmin runs the query just fine, after a long period of time...

Comment: How does creating a CSV file make it any better than creating a JSON file exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I might not be clear, but what I was trying to say was, if you use raw mysql **unbuffered** query e.g. `$mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)`; it won't store all the results in memory when returning the data , which is the case with `mysql_query`. It will sequentially read the data in chunks, especially useful in your case, as it is more memory efficient. If you go through the link I provided they have given detailed explanation. phpMyAdmin might be using something similar, as it seems to work for you.

Comment: CSV is streaming the data to the file and not storing it in the memory, like **$json** array is doing.

Comment: Ok, so I'm guessing that this can't be done using JSON format, and should reconsider only using CSV format :(

Comment: @SolomonClosson You can use CSV, it might be easier. But I have also updated my answer, with a possible solution which creates a json using streaming. I have experimented writing and reading and it works fine. I have put some explanation around it too. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome, will give it a try and let you know, +1

Answer (score 3):

### Creating the file

The problem with your code is you are trying to fit whole dataset into the memory, which eventually will fail as soon as your database gets large enough. To overcome this you have to fetch the data in batches.

We are going to generate the query multiple times so I extracted your query into a function. I skipped passing required parameters though (or making them global if you will) for brevity so you have to get this to work by yourself.

```
function generate_query($select, $limit = null, $offset = null) {
    $query = 'SELECT ' . $select . '
    FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p
    INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' AS pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
    LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON (oi.order_id = p.ID)
    LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON (oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id)
    WHERE p.post_type = "shop_order"' . (!empty($exclude_post_statuses) ? ' AND p.post_status NOT IN ("' . implode('","', $exclude_post_statuses) . '")' : '') . (!empty($start_date) ? ' AND post_date >= "' . $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . (!empty($end_date) ? ' AND post_date <= "' . $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . '
    ORDER BY p.ID ASC';

    if ($limit && $offset) {
        $query .= ' LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Now we will get results from the db in batches, we define the batch count that is the number of records per iteration that we will load into the memory. You can later on play with this value to find one that will be fast enough and won't make PHP crash. Keep in mind we want to reduce the number of database queries as much as possible:

```
define('BATCH_COUNT', 500);
```

Before we create the loop we need to know how many iterations (database calls) we will make, so we need the total order count. Having this and the batch count, we can calculate this value easily:

```
$orders_count = $wpdb->get_col(generate_query('COUNT(*)'));
$iteration_count = ceil($orders_count / BATCH_COUNT);
```

As a result we would like to have a huge JSON string inside the result file. Since with each iteration we will have a separate JSON containing an array of objects, we will simply strip the `[` and `]` from each side of the JSON string and put that string into the file.

Final code:

```
define('FILE', 'dump.json');
file_put_contents(FILE, '[');

for ($i = 0; $i < $iteration_count; $i++) {
    $offset = $i * BATCH_COUNT;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results(
        generate_query($select_data, BATCH_COUNT, $offset),
        ARRAY_A
    );

    // do additional work here, add missing arrays etc.
    // ...

    // I assume here the $result is a valid array ready for
    // creating JSON from it
    // we append the result file with partial JSON

    file_put_contents(FILE, trim(json_encode($result), '[]'), FILE_APPEND);
}

file_put_contents(FILE, ']', FILE_APPEND);
```

Congratulations, you have just created your first huge JSON dump ;) You should run this script in the command line so it can get as long as it needs to, there's no need to modify the memory limit from now on, because we are never going to hit the limit hopefully.

### Sending the file

Streaming large files with PHP is easy and [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39897872/997162) on SO many times. However I personally don't recommend you doing anything time consuming in PHP, because it sucks as a long running process, either in the command line or as a file server.

I assume you are using Apache. You should consider using [SendFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) and let Apache do the hard work for you. This method is far more efficient when dealing with huge files. This method is very easy, all you need to do is pass the path to the file in the header:

```
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $path_to_the_file);
```

Should you use Nginx there's [XSendFile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) support as well.

This method does not use a lot of memory, does not block the PHP process. The file does not need to be accessible in the webroot too. I use XSendFile all the time to serve 4K videos to authenticated users.

Comment: I don't understand how just adding this header to the php file will make this happen?  The answers you point to don't even use `X-Sendfile`

Comment: Also, I need to create the file first, so sending a path to a file that isn't even created, how?

Comment: So the problem is the process of generating the file gets interrupted due to PHP memory limits?

Comment: Ok, that tells me the problem, but how to stream it?  What's the solution?

Comment: I asked you a question and you did not answer. Problem is with the word streaming, I believe you mean something else by that. Streaming is a process of sending a file over a wire in chunks and I wrote you a solution to that problem. However I’m starting to think that the real problem is that you are incapable of generating that dump file of your data. Am I right?

Comment: I am trying to stream the dump file in PHP, and it seems that you are saying that it is not possible, but others have already done this.  Looks at CSV Import Suite plugin for Woocommerce.  This plugin successfully streams all orders and Woocommerce customers to a CSV file, but I don't care about CSV, I'm interested in doing this with JSON only.  In any case, there must be a way to do this in JSON format that does not involve manually performing operations that a novice would not normally know how to do.  It needs to stream the creation of the json file somehow.

Comment: Where did I say it is impossible. I will update my answer today.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should ask yourself a question: *Do I need to write database dump myself?*

If not then you can simply use some service that will do the work for you. [Mysqldump-php](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php) should be able to do the job.

Then you can simply:

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/mysqldump-php-2.0.0/src/Ifsnop/Mysqldump/Mysqldump.php');
$dump = new Ifsnop\Mysqldump\Mysqldump('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'username', 'password');
$dump->start('storage/work/dump.sql');
```

This should create `.sql` file. However, you wanted `json` file. That shouldn't be a problem though. This tool will do the rest of the job: http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json

You can also find the source code of `sql2json` on github: https://github.com/martindrapeau/csvjson-app

Comment: A database dump will not work, I've asked myself that question already.  The database is really huge, and doing a database dump would not solve the performance issue on a site I am optimizing.  I am trying to reduce the database, and only grab what is needed, after some removals of plugins, etc.  This causes post ids to be out of alignment, and I'm trying to reduce these so that the new database auto increment columns are falling into line better.  mysqldump does not help here.

Comment: So, basically I have split this up to create a json file for every week for 10 years, which will create 520 json files, which I will than just loop through when performing the import functionality, if the file exist, and just delete each file after the import is finished.  This is unfortunately the only way I can think to do this.  Will require several calls to the import file, probably many, so have decided to setup a CRON to handle this instead of me reloading the page a couple hundred times.

Comment: I still don't think that what you are doing is the optimal solution. Databases can be large that is why we have them. Did you try to fix performance issues any other way? Maybe adding indexes? That is usually the easiest way how to increase database performance. If you have enough free space it might make a huge difference. Also, it looks like you are using WordPress. I believe you can optimize SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for `Generators`
http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php
https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-php-generators

Instead of creating that huge `$json` array, you iterate over each `$order_query` and perform operations on each iteration, negating the need to store it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you get **a large result set** from your query, which is heavy since you have 3 joins.

You could define a **limit and use offset** to get the data in **chunks** and then output your json in parts. The main problem is to somehow get the json data in memory and then access it to output in parts.

For the latter **cache** or a nosql database could be used. My solution will use cache and in particular memcache:

```
class Cache {

    private $cache;

    public function __construct($cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function addPostName($postName)
    {
        $this->addKeyToJsonObject('postNames', $postName);
    }

    public function addKeyToJsonObject($rootName, $key)
    {
        $childNames = $this->cache->get($rootName);
        if($childNames === false) {
            $this->cache->set($rootName, [$key]);
        }
        else {
            $childNamesList = $childNames;
            // not found
            if(array_search($key, $childNamesList) === false) {
                $childNamesList[] = $key;
                $this->cache->set($rootName, $childNamesList);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getPostNames()
    {
        return $this->cache->get('postNames');
    }
    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->cache->add($key, $value);
    }

    public function addPostIdsByNameAndType($postName, $type, $pid)
    {
        $this->addKeyToJsonObject($postName . '-' . $type, $pid);
    }

    public function getPostIdsByNameAndType($postName, $type)
    {
        return $this->cache->get($postName . '-' . $type);
    }

    public function addPostValueByNameTypeAndId($postName, $type, $pid, $value)
    {
        $this->cache->set($postName . '-' . $type . '-' . $pid, $value);
    }

    public function getPostValueByNameTypeAndId($postName, $type, $pid)
    {
        return $this->cache->get($postName . '-' . $type . '-' . $pid);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$memcache->flush();

$cache = new Cache($memcache);

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{"shop_order":{';

function getResultSet($wpdb, $offset = 1) {
    return $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT ' . $select_data . '
FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p
INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' AS pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON (oi.order_id = p.ID)
LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON (oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id)
WHERE p.post_type = "shop_order"' . (!empty($exclude_post_statuses) ? ' AND p.post_status NOT IN ("' . implode('","', $exclude_post_statuses) . '")' : '') . (!empty($start_date) ? ' AND post_date >= "' . $start_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . (!empty($end_date) ? ' AND post_date <= "' . $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '"' : '') . '
ORDER BY p.ID ASC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET ' . $offset, ARRAY_A);

}
$offset = 1;

$orders_query = getResultSet($wpdb, 1);
while(!empty($orders_query)) {
    cacheRowData($cache, $orders_query);
    $offset = $offset + 1000;
    $orders_query = getResultSet($wpdb, $offset);
}

outputRowData($cache);

function cacheRowData($cache, $orders_query)
{
    foreach($orders_query as $order_query) {

        if(empty($order_query)) { continue; }
        $cache->addPostName($order_query['p_post_name']);

        // posts
        if (!empty($order_query['p_ID'])) {
            $cache->addPostIdsByNameAndType($order_query['p_post_name'],'posts', $order_query['p_ID']);

            $value = array_filter($order_query, function($k) {
                $is_p = strpos($k, 'p_');
                return $is_p !== FALSE && empty($is_p);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
            $cache->addPostValueByNameTypeAndId($order_query['p_post_name'],'posts', $order_query['p_ID'], $value);
        }
        if (!empty($order_query['pm_meta_id'])) {
        $cache->addPostIdsByNameAndType($order_query['p_post_name'],'postmeta', $order_query['pm_meta_id']);

        $value = array_filter($order_query, function($k) {
            $is_pm = strpos($k, 'pm_');
            return $is_pm !== FALSE && empty($is_pm);
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
        $cache->addPostValueByNameTypeAndId($order_query['p_post_name'],'postmeta', $order_query['pm_meta_id'], $value);
    }
        // here do the same for "woocommerce_order_items" and "woocommerce_order_itemmeta"
    }
}

function outputRowData($cache)
{

    $cachedPostNames = $cache->getPostNames();
    $firstRow = true;

    foreach($cachedPostNames as $postName) {

        if(empty($postName)) { continue; }

        if($firstRow === false) {
            echo ',';
        }
        $firstRow = false;

        echo '"' . $postName . '":{';
        $postIds = $cache->getPostIdsByNameAndType($postName, 'posts');
        if(!$postIds) {
            $postIds = [];
        }

        // generate posts
        $postValues = [];
        foreach ($postIds as $postId) {
            $postValues[$postId] = $cache->getPostValueByNameTypeAndId($postName, 'posts', $postId);
        }

        $postMetaIds = $cache->getPostIdsByNameAndType($postName, 'postmeta');
        if(!$postMetaIds) {
            $postMetaIds = [];
        }
        $postMetaValues = [];
        foreach ($postMetaIds as $postMetaId) {
            $postMetaValues[$postMetaId] = $cache->getPostValueByNameTypeAndId($postName, 'postmeta', $postMetaId);
        }
        // here do the same for "woocommerce_order_items" and "woocommerce_order_itemmeta"

        echo '"posts":' . json_encode($postValues) . ',';
        echo '"postmeta":' . json_encode($postMetaValues);
        echo '}';
        ob_flush();
        flush();   // flush the output to start the download
    }
}


echo '}}';
```

Comment: This looks promising, will give it a go and let you know.  Forgot to pull over the `$select_data` variable inside of the `getResultSet` function though.

Comment: Sorry, had an error. I updated the code, should separate the cache & output code.

Answer (score 0):

So there are lot of things that you need to get working to this right. I will all the point that I have in mind.

**Termination by WebServer**

If you use Apache or Nginx/PHP-FPM, both by default have a timeout for the url that is hit. So even though you have used

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
```

To let the script run for long, but Apache, Nginx, PHP-FPM all have a timeout which won't allow your script to work. So you need fix these to get it working. You never mentioned which server you used. But a NGINX+PHP-FPM will result in 502 for sure with the default config.

**Memory Usage**

Even though you have used

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

If your memory needs rises high, PHP may start using paging and your code could become slow.

**PHP CLI or PHP Web?**

Not sure what is the frequency of execution here, but if it is low you can consider your data dumping script to be run through a PHP-CLI instead of HTTP. This would mean that you would run a PHP script directly through terminal to dump the JSON into a file and later use a URL to download the file directly

**Using X-Sendfile or X-Accel-Redirect**

If you are using apache you can send a header

```
header('X-Sendfile: /data/generated.json');
```

In case of Nginx you can send a

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /data/generated.json');
```

This you would do only in case you have decided to run the script as web and not as a CLI. When the generation of the JSON has finished, you don't want your script to read the file and server. You just want the webserver to care of it.

**Unbuffered query instead of WPDB Query**

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L2480

By default WPDB query fetches all the data into memory. But you can query the DB yourself using unbuffered query, this will not flood the memory

```
Example #1 Unbuffered query example: mysqli

<?php
$mysqli  = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$uresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo $row['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
$uresult->close();
?>
Example #2 Unbuffered query example: pdo_mysql

<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world", 'my_user', 'my_pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$uresult = $pdo->query("SELECT Name FROM City");
if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
?>
Example #3 Unbuffered query example: mysql

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_pass");
$db   = mysql_select_db("world");

$uresult = mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT Name FROM City");
if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($uresult)) {
       echo $row['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
?>
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

PS: There might be few more points that I am missing right now in my head, would update this soon